# Installation error in Mysql Library in Python

Tags: python, mysql, pip, mysql-connector

I am installing `mysql` and `mysql-connector-python` using pip in Python. Upon installing mysql, it is showing as `mysql -- 0.0.3` and on searching for mysql library, its showing:

Error while runnning my file

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mysql'
```

error in CMD

```
mysql : The term 'mysql' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included.
```

please Help :)

I tried to run `pip install mysql` and it is showing:

```
Requirement already satisfied: mysql in c:\users\chaks\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python310\site-packages (0.0.3)
```